# Merging the value as an additional input to the fully connected layer

Tags: keras, merge, neural-network, concatenation, keras-layer

I have an image dataset along with orientation information. I want to add this orientation info as additional information to the fully connected layer. I tried the below code for the same.

```
def build_model(inp_shape=(35, 35, 3), vector_shape=(1,)):

    base_model = keras.Sequential()

    base_model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation="relu", input_shape=inp_shape))

    base_model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    base_model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    base_model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

    base_model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation="relu"))
    base_model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    base_model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    base_model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.25))

    base_model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_last'))

    base_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
    base_model.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    base_model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    vector_model = keras.Sequential()
    vector_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu', input_shape=vector_shape))

    model = keras.layers.concatenate([base_model, vector_model], axis=-1)
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax'))

    model.summary()
    return model
```

but this results in below error.

```
ValueError: Layer concatenate_3 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'>. Full input: [<keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001FABED0F208>, <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000001FAB056A308>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.
```

Is this because of the way I give the input to the model as below?

```
model = build_model(inp_shape=data_shape, vector_shape=vector_shape)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), metrics=["accuracy"])

history = model.fit_generator(training_generator, steps_per_epoch=len(x_train) // batch_size, epochs=num_epochs,
                              shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Comment: you can do this without so many problems but pay attention to your training_generator... it should return 2 elements to fit your model: the input for the base part and the input for the vector part... did u take care of this?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thanks. I tried that as here. `x, y, z = load_data(data_path)  

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val, x_orient, y_orient = train_test_split(x, y, z, test_size=val_split, stratify=y, shuffle=True)  

data_gen = ImageDataGenerator()  

training_generator = data_gen.flow(x_train, y_train, x_orient,  batch_size=batch_size) `   where x is `images`, y is `labels` and z is `orientation array`. Is this correct? Because by using this, I still face issue with `datagen_flow`.

Comment: You should concat the output of the models, not the models itself: `concatenate([base_model.output, vector_model.output])`.

Comment: @keertikulkarni this is not the correct way to use a generator for multiple input sources... I see also y_orient... do u mean that your network must produce 2 outputs?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani @today, Thanks! I was able to resolve the issue. And `y_orient` is the orientation array for the validation set, but I guess I named it wrongly.